# MongoDB SocketIO pub sub performace over rooms

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io, publish-subscribe

I am recently trying an application with NodeJS, MongoDB and Socekt IO.

I just heard of SocketIO stores that can be used to cache the messages over the interaction between clients, I am having some doubts on it.

1. Which is better in terms of performance (SocketIO [Rooms](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Rooms) vs store pub sub) ?
2. Will [mong.socket.io](https://npmjs.org/package/mong.socket.io) suffice my requirement?
3. Is there any other advantages in selection pub-sub or Rooms?
4. **Or am i Completely mistaken ?**

Answer (score 0):

I think that redis would be the better choice here.
(https)://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO

Redis has the great benefit, that its implementation already supports pub/sub functionality native.
(http)://redis.io/topics/pubsub

By the way redis is a good choice for storing session data, because it supports expiring ((http)://redis.io/commands/expire) for keys, which means the database cleans up itself. A great advantage is, that redis supports persistence, which sound ideal for restoring for example messages or session data after a crash.
(http)://redis.io/topics/persistence

And for high workload there is also a way to replicate: (http)://redis.io/topics/replication